# If statements within function parameters; Branching types

Tags: c++, types, functional-programming

I've been programming in Clojure (a functional language) for a while now, and I have to use C++ for a class. I've been trying to use some of the functionality I've enjoyed in Clojure (e.g., higher-order functions, lambdas, argument threading, dynamic typing, etc.) but I've been running into some difficulties.

One thing that you're able to do in Clojure (and I assume other functional languages) is use pretty much any function anywhere. For example, an `if` statement in Clojure can be inserted into a function call's parameters/arguments, but in C++, that's not possible.

As a simplified example of something larger I'm doing, I'm trying to get the following to work:

```
println(if (true) { 100 } else { 200 });
```

I implemented the function `println` to accept any number of arguments; it works just like Clojure's `println` (similar to Java's `System.out.println`), but uses `cout`.

Obviously, probably the syntax for an `if` statement is that each branch has to have a semicolon afterward (barring the shorter-syntax alternative without brackets). So I added semicolons and put it in the function `println`, but that didn't work - the compiler threw an `expected expression` error.

So I turned to macros. At first, I implemented this:

```
#define if1(pred, expr_true, expr_false) \
   if (pred) {                           \
     return expr_true;                   \
   } else {                              \
     return expr_false;                  \
   }
```

and I put it in `println` like so:

```
println(if1(true, 100, 200));
```

But that caused the compiler to throw the same error.

So I figured that maybe I could wrap the `if` statement in a lambda (because in C++, functions can't be declared within a function call's arguments):

```
#define if2(pred, expr_true, expr_false) \
  []() -> decltype(auto){                \
    if (pred) { return expr_true;  }     \
    else      { return expr_false; }}()
```

I used it like so:

```
println(if2(true, 100, 200));
```

This time, apparently the compiler was no longer concerned with the `if` statement being in a weird place, and it compiled fine and printed the expected value, `100`.

However, when I tried `println(if2(true, "true!", 200))`, the compiler generated the following error:

```
error: 'decltype(auto)' in return type deduced as 'int' here but deduced as 'char const (&)[5]' in earlier return statement
```

How do I get around this error?

Also, generally, how do I declare the return type to vary based on different possible return types from branching conditional statements, given that `decltype(auto)` doesn't appear to work in those cases?

Thank you for your help!

***Note:*** I'm using g++ with the arguments `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c++1y`.

Comment: In C++ you can use the `condition ? if_true : if_false` expression, which evaluates to `if_true` if `condition` is true, else `if_false`.  Is that what you are after?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `boost::variant`.

```
#include <boost/variant.hpp>

template<typename T, typename U>
auto if2(bool cond, T const& t, U const& u)
{
    typedef boost::variant<T const&, U const&> vari;
    return cond ? vari(t) : vari(u);
}

int main()
{
    println( if2(rand() % 2 == 0, "true", 200) );
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bb39d153ca61fac1)

Comment: I chose this answer because it actually compiles. The other answers were very helpful and informative, but none of them actually got the code to work. Thank you all!

Answer (score 2):

For me, I'd use the ternary operator. `(<expression>? <value-if-true>: <value-if-false>)`

Usage:

```
println("%d", (true? 100: 200));
```

Comment: What if I want to do : `println("%_what_?", cond? orange : apple);`? Where `orange` and `apple` are incompatible with each other. Also, what should I write in `_what_` place?

Comment: You should use the C++ standard `iostream` library, which includes function `std::cout`. Usage: `std::cout << (cond? orange: apple);` The `std::cout` function is overloaded to accept a number of different types.

Comment: @chucksys: But if orange is not convertible to apple's type, and apple is not convertible to orange's type, then the statement won't compile.

Comment: @Nawaz You could do something like this: `cond ? (std::cout << orange) : (std::cout << apple)`

Comment: @cdhowie Then there will be no need to use the ternary operator; a simple if-statement would suffice.

Comment: @chucksys Of course. Ultimately what OP wants isn't really possible in C++ without wrapper types (such as `boost::variant`).

Answer (score 2):

You can't really get around this error in vanilla C++, because overload resolution happens at compile time.  For example:

```
void foo(int a) { }
void foo(char const * a) { }

void bar(bool b)
{
    foo(if2(b, "true!", 200));
}
```

The compiler needs to know which `foo()` to call at compile time, and it can't do this if the type of result `if2()` evaluates to isn't known at compile time.  Therefore, the lambda must return *some specific type* and this means that the true expression and the false expression must be of the same type.

I would recommend using the ternary operator `?:` instead:

```
void bar(bool b)
{
    foo(b ? "true!" : 200);
}
```

This will still fail to compile, but you'll get a somewhat clearer error message:

```
error: operands to ?: have different types ‘const char*’ and ‘int’
```

Further, the ternary expression can implicitly convert one of the operands to be compatible with the type of the other operand, while lambda return type deduction is not as clever:

```
// error: inconsistent types ‘int’ and ‘double’ deduced for lambda return type
auto x = [] () { if (true) { return 0; } else { return 0.0; } };

// This works; y will be a double and the int would be implicitly converted.
auto y = true ? 0 : 0.0;
```